# Performing an Upsert in PageReferenceSave - Not updating Item.ID for Use In UnitTest

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, upsert

I have a test that creates a new record in our custom table - Service Offered. Whe I call my controller and save - It creates/updates the record correctly, and in my class the Debug.Assert gives me the records new ID. However, when trying to access this ID from my test class after the fact, the ID is not present, which breaks the subsequent steps.

Save Logic:

```
public PageReference save() {

    try {
      upsert Item;

      System.Debug('IN SAVE ID = ' + Item.Id);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
      return null;
    }

    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('saveURL') != null)
      return new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('saveURL'));
    else
      return new PageReference('/' + Item.Opportunity.Id);
  }
```

When I try to access the record afterwards,

```
 ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(new OpportunityLineItem());
    LineItemWizard C = new LineItemWizard(sc);
    C.Item.UnitPrice = 20;
    System.Debug('BEFORE SAVE ' + C.Item.Id);
    C.save();
    System.Debug('AFTER SAVE ' + C.Item.Id);
```

There is no id present.

And if I try to query it using the OpportunityID, I get no results either:

```
OpportunityLineItem oli = [Select ID, Quantity, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID = :OPP.Id];
```

Sorry, Posting all the code would be messy, but am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are inserting data from test class, most important part is that the test data is never created in your system. When you query for the data there would be nothing you would see.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that code below is within your testmethod:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(new OpportunityLineItem());
LineItemWizard C = new LineItemWizard(sc);
C.Item.UnitPrice = 20;
System.Debug('BEFORE SAVE ' + C.Item.Id);
C.save();
System.Debug('AFTER SAVE ' + C.Item.Id);
```

then the line

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(new OpportunityLineItem());
```

will not locate a specific OLI, as you are passing in an empty SObject

You would need

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = 
   new ApexPages.standardController(new OpportunityLineItem(id=theIdretrievedafterTheSave));
```

Comment: The problem is that using the code I have, I don't have an Id when returning from the save. That is the whole issue. The second call to the StandardController is passing in the newly saved C.Item, C.Item should in my class be recognized as a new record, but for some reason, in the actual class it is populated, but as soon as I leave the class and come back to the test class, the ID is empty. The results of both the 

System.Debug('BEFORE SAVE ' + C.Item.Id);
C.save();
System.Debug('AFTER SAVE ' + C.Item.Id); have no ID stored.

Comment: I realize you were trying to limit the code dump for use here at SFSE and we appreciate that. But I sense I'm missing something.  Once you return from save(), the testmethod can use a SOQL query to locate the saved OLI and use that to pass into the newly instantiated ApexPages.standardController